# Typescript compile error when using Opensea SDK and Web3

Tags: typescript, nestjs, web3js, opensea

It's a very simple code (a nest.js service) using [opensea.io sdk](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js#fetching-assets).

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { OpenSeaPort, Network } from 'opensea-js';
import { OpenSeaAsset } from 'opensea-js/lib/types';

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io');

const seaport = new OpenSeaPort(provider, {
  networkName: Network.Main,
});

const tokenAddress = '0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d';
const tokenId = '1';

@Injectable()
export class OpenseaService {
  async fetchTrendingAssets() {
    const asset: OpenSeaAsset = await seaport.api.getAsset({
      tokenAddress,
      tokenId,
    });
    return asset;
  }
}
```

It runs by `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts`.
But it stuck when compiling with `tsc`.
Here's the terminal log I'm seeing:

```bash
yarn run v1.22.17
$ rm -rf dist && tsc
node_modules/@0xproject/types/lib/index.d.ts:23:16 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'LogEntry'.

23     logs: Web3.LogEntry[];
                  ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@0xproject/types/lib/index.d.ts:39:60 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'DecodedLogEntry'.

39 export interface LogWithDecodedArgs<ArgsType> extends Web3.DecodedLogEntry<ArgsType> {
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@0xproject/types/lib/index.d.ts:41:35 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'LogEntry'.

41 export declare type RawLog = Web3.LogEntry;
                                     ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@0xproject/types/lib/index.d.ts:49:59 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'LogEntry'.

49     logs: Array<LogWithDecodedArgs<DecodedLogArgs> | Web3.LogEntry>;
                                                             ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/seaport.d.ts:7:11 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

7     web3: Web3;
            ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/seaport.d.ts:8:19 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

8     web3ReadOnly: Web3;
                    ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/seaport.d.ts:29:32 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'Provider'.

29     constructor(provider: Web3.Provider, apiConfig?: OpenSeaAPIConfig, logger?: (arg: string) => void);
                                  ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/types.d.ts:498:57 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'JSONRPCResponsePayload'.

498 export declare type Web3RPCCallback = Web3Callback<Web3.JSONRPCResponsePayload>;
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/types.d.ts:504:16 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'AbiType'.

504     type: Web3.AbiType | string;
                   ~~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/types.d.ts:511:28 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ConstructorStateMutability'.

511     stateMutability?: Web3.ConstructorStateMutability | string;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:19:49 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

19 export declare const confirmTransaction: (web3: Web3, txHash: string) => Promise<unknown>;
                                                   ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:42:49 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

42 export declare function personalSignAsync(web3: Web3, message: string, signerAddress: string): Promise<ECSignature>;
                                                   ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:48:49 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

48 export declare function isContractAddress(web3: Web3, address: string): Promise<boolean>;
                                                   ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:65:50 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

65 export declare function sendRawTransaction(web3: Web3, { from, to, data, gasPrice, value, gas }: Web3.TxData, onError: (error: Error) => void): Promise<string>;
                                                    ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:65:103 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'TxData'.

65 export declare function sendRawTransaction(web3: Web3, { from, to, data, gasPrice, value, gas }: Web3.TxData, onError: (error: Error) => void): Promise<string>;
                                                                                                         ~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:76:39 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

76 export declare function rawCall(web3: Web3, { from, to, data }: Web3.CallData, onError?: (error: Error) => void): Promise<string>;
                                         ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:76:70 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'CallData'.

76 export declare function rawCall(web3: Web3, { from, to, data }: Web3.CallData, onError?: (error: Error) => void): Promise<string>;
                                                                        ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:85:43 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

85 export declare function estimateGas(web3: Web3, { from, to, data, value }: Web3.TxData): Promise<number>;
                                             ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:85:81 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'TxData'.

85 export declare function estimateGas(web3: Web3, { from, to, data, value }: Web3.TxData): Promise<number>;
                                                                                   ~~~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:90:50 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

90 export declare function getCurrentGasPrice(web3: Web3): Promise<BigNumber>;
                                                    ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:96:54 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

96 export declare function getTransferFeeSettings(web3: Web3, { asset, accountAddress }: {
                                                        ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:151:62 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Web3' as a type.

151 export declare function validateAndFormatWalletAddress(web3: Web3, address: string): string;
                                                                 ~~~~

node_modules/opensea-js/lib/utils/utils.d.ts:161:77 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

161 export declare function getNonCompliantApprovalAddress(erc721Contract: Web3.ContractInstance, tokenId: string, accountAddress: string): Promise<string | undefined>;
                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/base_contract.d.ts:4:42 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

4     protected web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance;
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/base_contract.d.ts:7:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

7     constructor(web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance, defaults: Partial<TxData>);
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/wyvern_atomicizer.d.ts:15:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

15     constructor(web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance, defaults: Partial<TxData>);
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/wyvern_d_a_o.d.ts:102:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

102     constructor(web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance, defaults: Partial<TxData>);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/wyvern_exchange.d.ts:128:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

128     constructor(web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance, defaults: Partial<TxData>);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/wyvern_proxy_registry.d.ts:69:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

69     constructor(web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance, defaults: Partial<TxData>);
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/abi_gen/wyvern_token.d.ts:110:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'ContractInstance'.

110     constructor(web3ContractInstance: Web3.ContractInstance, defaults: Partial<TxData>);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/types.d.ts:47:37 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'LogEntryEvent'.

47 export declare type LogEvent = Web3.LogEntryEvent;
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/types.d.ts:56:60 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'DecodedLogEntry'.

56 export interface LogWithDecodedArgs<ArgsType> extends Web3.DecodedLogEntry<ArgsType> {
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/types.d.ts:59:59 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'LogEntry'.

59     logs: Array<LogWithDecodedArgs<DecodedLogArgs> | Web3.LogEntry>;
                                                             ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/types.d.ts:71:35 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'LogEntry'.

71 export declare type RawLog = Web3.LogEntry;
                                     ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-js/lib/types.d.ts:155:41 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'Provider'.

155 export declare type Web3Provider = Web3.Provider;
                                            ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-schemas/dist/index.d.ts:4:10 - error TS2614: Module '"web3"' has no exported member 'AbiType'. Did you mean to use 'import AbiType from "web3"' instead?

4 export { AbiType, } from 'web3';
           ~~~~~~~

node_modules/wyvern-schemas/dist/types.d.ts:56:16 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/netfan/oneandzeros/node-nft-backend/node_modules/web3/types/index"' has no exported member 'AbiType'.

56     type: Web3.AbiType.Event;
                  ~~~~~~~


Found 37 errors.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

And here's my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "modules/*": ["modules/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

`package.json` file is here:

```json
{
  "name": "nest-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nest.js Starter For Minimalists",
  "author": "CrazyOptimist",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
    "start:prod": "node -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/main.js",
    "start:hmr": "node dist/server",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "ts-typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm",
    "migration:create": "typeorm migration:create -d src/migrations",
    "migration:run": "yarn ts-typeorm migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "yarn ts-typeorm migration:revert",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.5",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.7.12",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.2",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "opensea-js": "^1.2.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.30",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "6.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.14",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack": "^5.17.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

#### Environment

- Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04
- Browser:  Not used
- Node.js Version: 16.13 (same behavior with v14.17)
- NPM Version: 8.1.0 (same with v6.4)

Is something wrong in the tsconfig, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the requirements first as listed here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/opensea-js-ex#installation

They require Node 8.x to work seamlessly.